# Queuing theory-Multiple server (reducing simple recurrence formulas)

Tags: recurrence-relations, self-learning, queueing-theory

[image]

The equations given in 6.3 have been reduced which really eases the computation in further studies. But I tried to find the method of reducing these but I could not find a way at all. Any hints will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This follows fairly directly by induction.  What is probably confusing
you is that the value of $n$ in the equilibrium equations is different
from the $n$ in the reduced equations.  Let us start with the no queue
situation.  (I'll rename $n$ to $m$ in the equilibrium equations to
reduce confusion.)

We have
\begin{align*}
0 &= -\lambda P_0 + \mu P_1&\qquad &\text{for $m=0$}\\
0 &= -(\lambda + m \mu) P_m + \lambda P_{m-1} + \mu(m+1) P_{m+1}
&\qquad &\text{for $1\le m \le k-1$} 
\end{align*}
and we want to prove that 
$$0 = -\lambda P_{n-1} + n\mu P_n \qquad \text{for $1\le n\le k$}.$$

It is easy to see that the equation holds for $n=1$ as that is just
the $m=0$ equilibrium equation.  Let us proceed by induction and
assume that the reduced equation holds for $n-1$ (assume $n>1$ as we
have already dealt with that.)  From the equilibrium equation for
$m=n-1$ we have 
$$0 = -(\lambda + (n-1) \mu) P_{n-1} + \lambda P_{n-2} + \mu n P_{n}$$
and from the last equilibrium equation we have
$$ \lambda P_{n-2} = (n-1) \mu P_{n-1}. $$
Combining the equations we get
$0 = -\lambda P_{n-1}  + n \mu P_{n}$ the $n$th reduced equation (the $-(n-1)\mu P_{n-1}$ and $(n-1)\mu P_{n-1} terms cancel.)

The other reduced equation is proved in exactly the same way.  We note
that it holds for $n=k$ (by the above induction) and then substitute
the last reduced equation into the appropriate equilibrium equation.
Lather, rinse, repeat.